# Child div is bigger than parent div

Tags: css

[image: Here is the image of the problem]

The plan is to make the child divs as big as there is space in the parent div.
Is there an option to implement the full height of the parent div onto the child elements?
I only know the css calc() as an option, but I do not want to implement this option.
Additionally I explained the problem within an image.

```css
.parent {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}

.child1,
.child2,
.child3 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: calc(100% - 253px);
}

.child1>*,
.child1>*>* {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
}

.child3 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <button class="button button1">10px 24px</button>
    <button class="button button2">12px 28px</button>
  </div>
  <div class="child1">
    <div><textarea></textarea></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should check a flexbox solution

Comment: Don't give the `.parent` a height and instead of `float`ing those children just `display:inline-block;` on them.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you with a flexbox solution, as it should be the best option for this scenario as far as i can think of.

Make your container as flex container, the child which has `.flex--1` class will take the full of the rest space.

```
.flex--1 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Check flexbox [doc](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for the detail.

```css
.flex-rows {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex--1 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.parent {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}

.child1,
.child2,
.child3 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: calc(100% - 253px);

}

.child1>*,
.child1>*>* {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
}

.child3 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent flex-rows">
  <div>
    <button class="button button1">10px 24px</button>
    <button class="button button2">12px 28px</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex--1">
    <div class="child1">
      <div><textarea></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
It´s a nice solution, but is there also a solution for the textarea?
In your example it gets bigger as the parent.

Comment: Yes, what's your expectation for the textarea, you want a fixed textarea? Actually check the link in the answer to learn flexbox will help you a lot.